# Spotify Omniauth

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, spotify

I'm trying to do OmniAuth in rails 4 for spotify. I almost have it but for some reason, the redirect URI isn't working. *I am using Devise with omniauth* These are my files:

User.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable

  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable,
  :omniauthable, :omniauth_providers => [:spotify]

  def self.from_omniauth(auth)
    where(provider: auth.provider, uid: auth.uid).first_or_create do |user|
      user.provider = auth.provider
      user.uid = auth.uid
      user.email = auth.info.email
      user.password = Devise.friendly_token[0,20]
    end
  end
end
```

My Callbacks controller to handle callbacks

```
class CallbacksController <  Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController
  def spotify
    @user = User.from_omniauth(request.env["omniauth.auth"])
    sign_in_and_redirect @user
  end
end
```

My Devise.rb snippet:

```
  config.omniauth :spotify, client_id, client_secret,scope: 'playlist-read-private user-read-private user-read-email'
```

My Routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
    devise_for :users, :controllers => { :omniauth_callbacks => 'callbacks' }
    get '/users/auth/callback', to: 'callbacks#spotify'
end
```

And lastly, the link leading up to the login:

```
<%= link_to 'Sign in with Spotify', user_omniauth_authorize_path(:spotify) %>
```

But for some reason, whenever I try to log into spotify, it says **invalid redirect URI**

Comment: make sure you have entered the redirect uri on spoity site correctly something like this "http://localhost:3000/users/auth/spotify/callback"

Comment: On spotify settings `redirect url` should be `localhost:3000/users/auth/callback`

Comment: I made sure of it. Unfortunately, the redirect URLs are all correctly typed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I figured out a solution to my particular problem:

- When it was giving me the error of "invalid redirect URI", I looked at the URI it was trying to go to and I simply used that.
- Then I got a second error which gave me a SSL Cert error so I used "gem certified" to fix that. THEN, it gave me a third problem of unauthorized access (the callback returned a failed request). What was happening was that I was trying to use OmniAuth twice. I had two files:

  A) OmniAuth.rb
  and B) Devise.rb

Both of these files were making API calls and it was messing it up. So to anyone having this problem- don't use both omniauth and devise. Honestly, after the first initial hiccup, I found devise to be way more useful than making your own User model and applying omniauth to that. Devise is more comprehensive!